# Как вычислить сумму всех строк столбца?

Tags: oracle, запрос, sql, plsql, база-данных

```
select distinct tst.p_komp, mg.meri_gp_id,
   case when (stoim_rub * 0.75)>150000 and tst.p_komp = 75 and mg.meri_gp_id=ts.meri_gp
                    then 150000
        when (stoim_rub * 0.5)>83000and tst.p_komp = 50  and mg.meri_gp_id=ts.meri_gp 
                    then 105000
        when ts.tex_sr_ttp=323544962 and mg.meri_gp_id=ts.meri_gp 
                    then stoim_rub * tst.p_komp / 100
        when ts.tex_sr_ttp=322897618 and mg.meri_gp_id=ts.meri_gp 
                    then stoim_rub * tst.p_komp / 100
   end summ_komp
  from all_tbl_meri_gp mg join (select p_komp,meri_gp from all_tbl_kompen_ts) tst on mg.meri_gp_id = tst.meri_gp,
       all_tbl_ts_ttp ts
```

на выходе запроса получается таблица у которой есть столбец summ_komp.
Дак вот вопрос в том как вычислить сумму всех строк этого столбца?

Comment: ок, извиняюсь возможно не так описал вопрос, нужно запрос написанный выше изменить так, чтобы выводилась сумма столбца summ_komp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему не так?

```
select sum(summ_komp) from
(
select distinct tst.p_komp, mg.meri_gp_id,
   case when (stoim_rub * 0.75)>150000 and tst.p_komp = 75 and mg.meri_gp_id=ts.meri_gp
                    then 150000
        when (stoim_rub * 0.5)>83000and tst.p_komp = 50  and mg.meri_gp_id=ts.meri_gp 
                    then 105000
        when ts.tex_sr_ttp=323544962 and mg.meri_gp_id=ts.meri_gp 
                    then stoim_rub * tst.p_komp / 100
        when ts.tex_sr_ttp=322897618 and mg.meri_gp_id=ts.meri_gp 
                    then stoim_rub * tst.p_komp / 100
   end summ_komp
  from all_tbl_meri_gp mg join (select p_komp,meri_gp from all_tbl_kompen_ts) tst on mg.meri_gp_id = tst.meri_gp,
       all_tbl_ts_ttp ts
    ) X
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(`summ_komp`) AS `all_summ_komp`
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `summ_komp`
```

Comment: summ_komp недопустимый идентификатор

Comment: Вы написали: "...на выходе запроса получается таблица у которой есть столбец summ_komp.", - смотрите что там у вас получается и группируйте как нужно. Я привёл пример как вычисляется сумма строк столбца.

Comment: Видимо необходимо было дополнить код для получения результата, а не в отдельном запросе.

Comment: ок, извиняюсь возможно не так описал вопрос, нужно запрос написанный выше изменить так, чтобы выводилась сумма столбца summ_komp

Comment: @CrazyTimon, ты предлагаешь сделать за тебя твою работу?

Answer (score 1):

```
select tst.p_komp, mg.meri_gp_id,
   sum(case when (stoim_rub * 0.75)>150000 and tst.p_komp = 75 and mg.meri_gp_id=ts.meri_gp
                    then 150000
        when (stoim_rub * 0.5)>83000and tst.p_komp = 50  and mg.meri_gp_id=ts.meri_gp 
                    then 105000
        when ts.tex_sr_ttp=323544962 and mg.meri_gp_id=ts.meri_gp 
                    then stoim_rub * tst.p_komp / 100
        when ts.tex_sr_ttp=322897618 and mg.meri_gp_id=ts.meri_gp 
                    then stoim_rub * tst.p_komp / 100
   end) summ_komp
  from all_tbl_meri_gp mg join (select p_komp,meri_gp from all_tbl_kompen_ts) tst on mg.meri_gp_id = tst.meri_gp,
       all_tbl_ts_ttp ts
group by tst.p_komp, mg.meri_gp_id
```